# Update columns of spark dataframe of type Map with desired key and value

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a following spark dataframe where all the columns (except for primary key column emp_id) consist of a map (with keys 'from' and 'to' which can have null values). I want to evaluate 'from' and 'to' of each column(except emp_id) and add a new key to the map(named 'change') which has a value of 
a) 'insert' if 'from' value is null and 'to' is not null
b) 'delete' if 'to' value is null and 'from' is not null
b) 'update' if 'from' and 'to' are not null & 'from' value is different from 'to' value

Note: columns which have null value will remain untouched.

How can we achieve this in Scala.

```
|emp_id|emp_city             |emp_name                    |emp_phone            |emp_sal                    |emp_site                          |

|1     |null                 |[from -> Will, to -> Watson]|null                 |[from -> 1000, to -> 8000]|[from ->, to -> Seattle]          |
|3     |null                 |[from -> Norman, to -> Nate]|null                 |[from -> 1000, to -> 8000]|[from -> CherryHill, to -> Newark]|
|4     |[from ->, to -> Iowa]|[from ->, to -> Ian]        |[from ->, to -> 1004]|[from ->, to -> 8000]     |[from ->, to -> Des Moines]       |
```

Expected:

```
|emp_id|emp_city             |emp_name                    |emp_phone            |emp_sal                    |emp_site                          |

|1     |null                 |[from -> Will, to -> Watson, change -> update]|null                 |[from -> 1000, to -> 8000, change -> update]|[from ->, to -> Seattle, change -> insert]          |
|3     |null                 |[from -> Norman, to -> Nate, change -> update]|null                 |[from -> 1000, to -> 8000, change -> update]|[from -> CherryHill, to -> Newark, change -> update]|
|4     |[from ->, to -> Iowa, change -> insert]|[from ->, to -> Ian, change -> insert]        |[from ->, to -> 1004, change -> insert]|[from ->, to -> 8000, change -> insert]     |[from ->, to -> Des Moines, change -> insert]       |
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: can you share the schema of dataframe?

Comment: I am thinking/trying to add a column(for each column) which contains the desired 'change' map; then merge the two columns back. I don't have the code for it - but would appreciate if I get any guidance

Comment: root
 |-- emp_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- emp_city: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- emp_name: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- emp_phone: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- emp_sal: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- emp_site: map (nullable = true)
    key: string
    value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using `UDF`, which is not a great solution but I can't think of other solutions.

Try not to use `UDF` as possible

```
val updateMap = udf((input: Map[String, String]) => {
  if (input == null || input.isEmpty)
    Map.empty[String, String]
  else if (input("from") == null && input("to") != null)
    input + ("change" -> "insert")
  else if (input("from") != null && input("to") == null)
    input + ("change" -> "delete")
  else if (!(input("from").equals(input("to"))))
    input + ("change" -> "update")
  else
    Map.empty[String, String]
```

})

```
val result = df.columns.tail.foldLeft(df) { (acc, name) =>
  acc.withColumn(name, updateMap(col(name)))
}
```

Make sure your columns are `Map[String, String]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. with small modification to include `if (input == null)  null` this code works well for the use case. If there is a better solution without using UDF, even better.

Comment: Hi - this works well for when column value is of type Map[String, String].  If I want to extend this solution to Map[String, Any] meaning value can be of any type - how do we change this solution (Any is not supported in map apparently). @koiralo. any help from anyone is appreciated.